# Is it possible in mysql to dynamically translate IDs stored in a string?

Tags: mysql, replace

I'm importing comment data in mysql from one database to another where some data may already exist. Relevant here, our `comments` table has a column `display_text` of type `text`. Inside this column we have mentions to other users stored in the format "`@{{"user":id}}@`" where id is a number representing the user's id in another table. It is possible for a single comment to have multiple mentions needing updated ids as well.

Since these users may already exist in the new database, part of our import process populates an `id_translations` table with `old_id` and `new_id` columns mapping the user's id in the source database to their id in the new database. Is it possible to write a mysql UPDATE statement to find the format of our mentions, and replace only the id with the new id?

I already have a method for selecting only the comments that will need ids updated, so statements can be written as though they would update the entire table.

MySQL version 5.6. Here's a sample of what my tables look like.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `display_text` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `id_translations` (
  `old_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `new_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`old_id`, `new_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `comments` (`id`, `display_text`) VALUES
(1, 'Hey @{{"user":12}}@, look at this'),
(2, 'Thats pretty cool'),
(3, '@{{"user":41}}@ could you take a peek at this?');

INSERT INTO `id_translations` (old_id, new_id) VALUES (12, 100), (41, 101);
```

The goal would be for comments to look like:

```
1, 'Hey @{{"user":100}}@, look at this'
2, 'Thats pretty cool'
3, '@{{"user":101}}@ could you take a peek at this?'
```

Comment: *Is it possible to write a mysql UPDATE statement to find the format of our mentions, and replace only the id with the new id?* Of course this is possible. Provide some example (CREATE TABLE for src table, dst table, users mapping table + INSERT INTO with some sample data, 2-3-5 rows, + table-formatted desired dst table state). Also specify precise MySQL server version.

Comment: @Akina does that work?

Comment: @Akina MySQL version 5.6. I also added it to the question.

Comment: 5.6 is too old, the code will be too complex. Does stored procedure format is safe for you?

Comment: Yes, that should be okay.

Comment: how mana rows ar in th id_translations table ? and do you want to do the change only one time manually ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE replacing ()
BEGIN
    REPEAT
        UPDATE comments
        SET display_text = CONCAT( LEFT(display_text, LOCATE('@{{"user":', display_text) - 1),
                                   CHAR(0),
                                   ( SELECT new_id 
                                     FROM id_translations 
                                     WHERE old_id = 0 + SUBSTRING(display_text FROM LOCATE('@{{"user":', display_text) + 10)),
                                   CHAR(1),
                                   SUBSTRING(display_text FROM LOCATE('}}@', display_text) + 3))
        
        WHERE LOCATE('@{{"user":', display_text);
    UNTIL !ROW_COUNT() END REPEAT;
    UPDATE comments
    SET display_text = REPLACE(REPLACE(display_text, CHAR(0), '@{{"user":'), CHAR(1), '}}@');
END
```

**<kbd>[DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=9a9e559f26dae851bb1f96e5ba320ae6)</kbd>**